# Angular FormGroup is undefined inside a local method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formgroups

I have 2 components in parallel and i am trying to inject 1 component into other. Below are my component files:

**RegisterComponent.html**

```
<mat-tab #tab label="Contact Details">
  <ng-template matTabContent>
    <app-contact-details></app-contact-details>
  </ng-template>
</mat-tab>

<button type="button" (click)="changeTabOrStepViaContinue()" class="">Continue</button>
```

**RegisterComponent.ts**

```
changeTabOrStepViaContinue() {
    if (this.tabGroup._tabs.first.isActive) {
      this.tabGroup.selectedIndex += 1;
    } else if (this.tabGroup._tabs.last.isActive /* &&  this.isContactFormValid() */) {
        this.contactDetails.validateContactDetails(); //throws Error
      console.log("Contact details form: ", this.contactDetailsForm);
    } else if (this.isPersonalDetailsFormValid()) {
        this.tabGroup.selectedIndex += 1;
    }
  }
```

**ContactDetailsComponent.ts(Component being injected)**

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Contct det ngOnInit fired......")
    this.contactDetailsForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      primaryMobile: ['', [Validators.required]],
      primaryMobileOwner: ['', [Validators.required]],
      primaryEmail: ['', [Validators.required]],
      primaryEmailOwner: ['', [Validators.required]],
      landLine: [''],
      country: ['', [Validators.required]],
      pinCode: ['', [Validators.required]],
      flat: ['', [Validators.required]],
      street: [''],
      postOffice: ['', [Validators.required]],
      locality: ['', [Validators.required]],
      district: ['', [Validators.required]],
      state: ['', [Validators.required]]
    })
}

validateContactDetails(): boolean {
    console.log(this.contactDetailsForm);
    Object.keys(this.contactDetailsForm.controls).forEach(elt => {
      this.contactDetailsForm.get(elt).markAsTouched();
    })
    if (this.contactDetailsForm.valid) {
      this.contactDetails.emit(this.contactDetailsForm);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

I have made the `ContactDetailsComponent` a service by including `@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})` and also injected it inside the constructor of `RegisterComponent` as `constructor(private contactDetails:ContactDetailsComponent)`.

When i select the particular mat-tab, the ngOnInit for `ContactDetailsComponent` is fired (it is loaded lazily since inside the ng-template) but on click of continue button, it shows an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined`.

Why is the FormGroup `undefined` inside a local function?

**Update**

I consoled the `this` context for `ContactDetailsComponent` and found that it doesn't have the `contactDetailsForm` property. Then i changed the variable declaration from `contactDetailsForm:FormGroup` to `contactDetailsForm:FormGroup=new FormGroup({})` and then it was registered on `this` but the validations put on FormControls inside the ngOnInit are not working anymore. I also added another FormGroup to the component and the same thing is happening. It looks like `this` is only registering properties which are initialized, though i am not sure why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to call a child method from a parent?

From what I'm seeing, you don't need to inject anything, unless its needed somewhere else that you are not telling us about. You can just add an id to your app-contact-details and use a ViewChild to get the reference. There are multiple ways to use a ViewChild, this one might not be the best for you but its just an example.

```
<app-contact-details #contactDetail></app-contact-details>

@ViewChild('contactDetail') contactDetail: ContactDetailsComponent; // In the parent ts file
```

Then if you want to see if it has been initilized, check in ngAfterViewInit of the parent where you should have access to the children function (you might need to cast the contactDetail as your component type, or you a different ViewChild initialization) if they are public because at this point the OnInit of the children should have been called.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
     // you can try to print your form
  }
```

The reason why your form isnt initialized is because you are not referencing the right instance, unless the component is a singleton. Using content projection(like you are doing) the component is going to be initialized as soon as angular starts displaying it(this is where OnInit is being called in the child).

Comment: thanks for the reply. Actually, the components dot really have a parent child relationship. they are sibling components. And the ```contactDetails``` component has to be used at at-least 5 different places so that is why i have made it as a service

Comment: It's not a sibling if you are injecting it using content projection. Using a component in 5 different places doesn't require a service, that's the point of using components!

Comment: i also tried using the answer given by you and it throws an error ```cannot read property 'validateContactDetails' of undefined```

Comment: Where did you call it from?

Comment: from inside the ```RegisterComponent```. ts file

Comment: Yeah but which lifecycle hook

Comment: actually I called it inside a function called on button click.

Comment: If it's undefined it's because the viewchild isn't being initialized correctly, look the angular doc since there are multiple ways to do it.

Comment: i changed the viewchild definition type from ```ElementRef``` to ```ContactDetailsComponent``` and it worked. Update your answer so that i can accept it. I spent a whopping 2 days trying to understand why it wasn't working. Thanks a ton man :-)

Comment: If you look closely I said that you might need to cast it!

Comment: Although i still don't understand why does the context get lost in case of a service since when originally i posted the question, the ```ContactDetailsComponent``` was a service

Comment: It's because the instance that you are injecting is not the one being displayed

Comment: @SamarthSaxena is there a reason why you unaccepted the answer?